# How to run test scripts in chrome?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

As we know that there is not as such problem in running test scripts with the IE or FF,but it takes a lot of time and mental efforts  to run test scripts via Chrome.As it needs Chrome driver (chrome.exe) for running  the test scripts.So the question can be why we need only Chrome Driver to run test cases and not FF-Driver or IE-Driver for the same.

Comment: There is a seperate Chromium project build and webdriver makes a connection to the executables.
 so thats why we need to incorporate the .exe path in Chrome.
 For IE and Firefox:-
There is IEDriver and Firefox Driver Implemented